# Analyticity when numerator is a factor of denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

[image: It's okay if you cannot see the picture. The body contains all the information needed.]

---

I'm trying to determine the region of analyticity for $f(z) = \frac{z^2+z+1}{z^6-1}$.
I get that $f(z)= \frac{z^2+z+1}{(z^3-1)(z^3+1)} = \frac{z^2+z+1}{(z-1)(z^2+z+1)(z^3+1)} = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z^3+1)} $.

Hence,the function is not analytic when $z =1, z^3 = -1 $.

I calculate the $z $ values such that $z^3 = -1 $:
$z^3 = -1 = \cos{(\pi +2k\pi)} + i \sin{(\pi + 2k\pi)} = e^{i(\pi + 2k\pi)}$.
Three distinct values that I get from the equation is:
$z = -1, \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}- i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\therefore z \in \{z\in \mathbb{C}: z \notin \{-1, \frac{1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}- i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\}\}$

However, the answer to this question states:

The function f is analytic away from the zeros of $z^6 −1$. These zeros are the sixth roots of unity $e^{2πik/6}, k = 0, 1, 2, . . . , 5.$ On the picture the region of analyticity is everything except the black dots.

And the picture has six dots. However, I only have four dots. Which answer is correct?

Comment: Technically, the function as written is undefined at all the sixth roots of unity, and so cannot be analytic at those six points.  You aren't working with the original function, though -- you are working with a function which is equal at all points other than the roots of $z^2+z+1$ (because you've assumed $\frac{z^2+z+1}{z^2+z+1}=1$).

Comment: I see. It seems odd to me that it's the original function that we have to analyze, even though it has common factors in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: A function like this is just a set of instructions, and it can't be followed at those points.  It might seem like a pedantic point... but it is important to understand the pedantic point in order to understand why and when it can be ignored.